# Embed audio player HTML

Tags: html, audio, media-player

I am a newbe in HTML and I want to embed an audio player which plays an mp3 file from a link from dropbox. I took a sample code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) however, is doesn't work. It opens a player but doesn't play. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
<audio controls>    
<source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8besx3yh043u4qn/TestFile.mp3?dl=0" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You point to the wrong source. This link actually points to a html file whose name is rewritten by the web server software. (If I follow this link, a file that starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` is opened, that is an indicator that this file is an HTML-website)

If you do a right-click on the player and select to examine the element you'll find the real link to this file under the preview-auto_container element.

So the audio element of your file needs to look like:

```
<audio>
<source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/KRfRP3OWPuNXyfpYKUjCQOUzNIoE6o66TvxCHu6xKh5fErZ22kJHCOCvJ0TeCccu/file?dl=0&duc_id=dropbox_duc_id" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```